# Regular Expression for anything in Between ${something}

Tags: regex

I am a newbie in regular expression, I have written regular expression for ${serviceName} basicly I want to take the words in between ${ } So I already wrote regular expression for this that is perfectly fine

```
"\\$\\{(\\w+)\\}"
```

But what I want to take any values not only the words which are in between ${serviceName.1.Type}.So can you guys help me with regular expression for **${serviceName.1.Type}**.
I hope my question is clear.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to test regular expressions is https://regex101.com/

> \w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

If you want to match anything you can replace it with: .*

> .* matches any character (except for line terminators)

You might want to add a "?" at the end to match to first "}"

> *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed

Also you don't need to escape the { } in this case

So what you want is:
`"\\${(.*?)}"`

Comment: Thanks so much that's what I am looking for. So mark this question as resolved.

Comment: Just one more question sorry for that ..
What is the significance ? here.

Comment: I've edited to copy the definition of *? from regex101. If you had a line with `{ return "${Hello}"; }`. Then `"\\${(.*?)}"` will match `${Hello}` and `"\\${(.*)}"` will match `${Hello}"; }`

Answer (score 0):

`\$\{([\w?\.?\d?\s?]+)\}`

This expression captures as a group everything that appears between {} 
You can then call the group with the expression $1

[On this web](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Find_/_Replace(%7B'option':'Regex','string':'%5C%5C$%5C%5C%7B(%5B%5C%5Cw?%5C%5C.?%5C%5Cd?%5C%5Cs?%5D%2B)%5C%5C%7D'%7D,'$1',true,true,true,false)&input=JHtzZXJ2aWNlTmFtZS4xLlR5cGV9) you will see your exercise solved and if other expressions have some additional character you can try to add it. Now it is prepared for points `\.` , spaces `\s`, letters `\w` and digits `\d`